# How to stream object from AWS S3 to browser using Sinatra and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sinatra

I was able to stream an S3 object from disk to the browser using the following post request in Ruby:

```
post '/api/s3/download/?' do
   filepath = "/tmp/test.txt"
   send_file(filepath, :filename => File.basename(filepath))
end
```

And the following AngularJS in the javascript:

```
$http.post('/api/s3/download/')
  .then(function(response) {
    var blob = new Blob([response.data]);
    var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const anchor = angular.element('<a></a>');
    anchor.attr('href', objectUrl);
    anchor.attr('download', source);
    anchor.css('display', 'none');
    angular.element(document.body).append(anchor);
    anchor[0].click();
  }, function(error_msg) {
    console.log(error_msg);
  });
```

I've tried the following in Ruby to get an S3 object as a `StringIO` where `source` is the S3 object key:

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new
bucket = s3.bucket('my_bucket')
data = bucket.object(source).get
```

Then I tried returning `data.body` as the response to the javascript but that didn't work.

How can I take a StringIO object and send it to the browser as an octet-stream without materializing the file to disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by using the following endpoint:

```
get '/api/s3/download' do
  source = params[:source]
  headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream'
  headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=#{source}"
  stream do |out|
    s3.client.get_object(bucket: 'my_bucket', key: source) do |chunk|
      out << chunk
    end
    out.flush
  end
end
```

And doing the following on the front end in Javascript opens a new tab in the browser that the download happens through:

```
$window.open('/api/s3/download?source=' + source), '_blank');
```